# Apply policy to specific users OR computers

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

I was directed to post my question here from stackoverflow.

Need some guidance implementing a policy. Specifically a block removable storage policy.

Let's say I have 100 computers named PC1-PC100. PC1-PC10 need to allow removable storage no matter whom logs in. Additionally, a couple user accounts need access to removable storage no matter what computer they log into. The other computers should block removable storage unless the 2 specified users are logged in.

I have tried this by creating a security group, adding the computers list to it, creating a policy that targets Authenticated Users which blocks removable storage at the user level, and then added delegations for the whitelisted computer security group and the 2 user accounts, with a Deny for Apply Group Policy. The delegations worked for the 2 user accounts, but removable storage did not work on the computers in the security group unless the 2 mentioned accounts were logged in.

Can someone kindly point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you're asking if you should allow people with certain accounts to plug in removable devices (mainly USB) on certain computers, right?

Comment: Hello and thank you for the response. It doesn't seem as if you are understanding the request. Perhaps if I made it a bulleted list:

1. Block USB Removable Storage on all devices, except -

2. For a list of specific computers, while also allowing -

3. 2 specific users to access removable storage regardless of the computer they are logged into.

Does that help?

Comment: I used the example of 100 computers labled PC1 through PC100. PC1 through PC10 need to allow users to access removable storage regardless of who logs in. The 2 users, let's call them Operations and Management, need to be able to access removable storage on any of the 100 PCs.